# Add file attachments/meta to a custom Taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I'd like to be able to upload a .pdf attachment to each Custom Post Type Taxonomy item. I've found some extensions that add meta fields to Taxonomies, but they don't support files.

Is it possible to do this? How?

Answer (score 1):

this tutorial will definitly solve your problem
http://en.bainternet.info/wordpress-taxonomies-extra-fields-the-easy-way/

Yes i have used it to add feature images to the custom taxonomy terms.It depends how you registering the custom post .If you have registered the  custom post as plugin from plugin directory , then you need to paste the downloaded folder i.e Tax-meta-class in directory of your custom post. 
Other wise you may also  copy Tax-meta-class in theme directory and register the post form functions.php
And i don't think that it needs to be used like a plugin.

Just one problemO . Every thing is working fine on localhost  but when i transfer my the site to live server then i am unable to get the images.May i need to upload the files again
Waiting for the author to reply
If you don't face any problem let me know.
alll d best

Comment: have you ever used this? I read the post and downloaded the files, but I don't really undertand how to use it. Is this a plugin? Should I place it in my theme?